# How can I change size of any specific character in eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, console, output, windows-11

how can increase size of any specific character of eclipse's console in windows11 ? I know how to change size of font size and color but I want increase size of space" " in my output.
want to increase size of only " " and not other characters .

Comment: You can't really change a single character. Unicode does have several different spaces characters with different widths U+2003 "em space" for example. But since the console uses a fixed width font that may not help.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the Eclipse.app is a setting for the font size. To make the fonts globally larger edit Eclipse.app » Contents » Eclipse » eclipse.ini and remove the line

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts`

from the file. Save the file and restart Eclipse.

Comment: The question is about changing a single character size, not everything.